Android Studio Koala Preview: Cannot find quick settings in Running devices window
According to developer tool enhancements talk from Google IO 2024, there is suppose to be a Quick Settings option in Running Devices window that allows changing dark mode, language, etc. directly from Android Studio. However, when I downloaded Koala preview I cannot find that option. Anyway to enable that feature?

And this is what was shown in the presentation 

Yes, I couldn't find it either. Just wondering what I missed.

The mentioned function is available in Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2. Make sure you have downloaded Canary build (not 2024.1.1 Beta 2)

Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2 Canary 4
Build #AI-241.15989.150.2412.11905440, built on May 30, 2024
I'm on this build but the option is not turned on
